# In C++, how to return different generic types depending on argument in a class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class Pair
{
private:
    T1 first;
    T2 second;

public:
    void SetFirst(T1 first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }
    void SetSecond(T2 second)
    {
        this.second = second;
    }
    T1 GetFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }
    T2 GetSecond()
    {
        return second;
    }
};
```

How could I implement two single methods `SetValue()` and `GetValue()`, instead of the four I have, that decides depending on parameters which generic type that should be used? For instance I'm thinking the `GetValue()` method could take an `int` parameter of either 1 or 2 and depending on the number, return either a variable of type `T1` or `T2`. But I don't know the return type beforehand so is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: If you have getters and setters that just get and set something, just make it public.

Comment: I am not certain, if it would solve your problem, but maybe it provide you some enlightment - look for std::tuple and std::get.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you want and not exactly what you asked but...

I propose the use of a wrapper base class defined as follows

```
template <typename T>
class wrap
 {
   private:
      T  elem;

   public:
      void set (T const & t)
       { elem = t; }

      T get () const
       { return elem; }
 };
```

Now your class can be defined as

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Pair : wrap<T1>, wrap<T2>
 {
   template <typename T>
   void set (T const & t)
    { wrap<T>::set(t); }

   template <typename T>
   T get () const
    { return wrap<T>::get(); }
 };
```

or, if you can use C++11 and variadic templates and if you define a type traits `getType` to get the Nth type of a list,

```
template <std::size_t I, typename, typename ... Ts>
struct getType
 { using type = typename getType<I-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct getType<0U, T, Ts...>
 { using type = T; };
```

you can define `Pair` in a more flexible way as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Pair : wrap<Ts>...
 {
   template <typename T>
   void set (T const & t)
    { wrap<T>::set(t); }

   template <std::size_t N, typename T>
   void set (T const & t)
    { wrap<typename getType<N, Ts...>::type>::set(t); }

   template <typename T>
   T get () const
    { return wrap<T>::get(); }

   template <std::size_t N>
   typename getType<N, Ts...>::type get ()
    { return wrap<typename getType<N, Ts...>::type>::get(); }
 };
```

Now the argument of `set()` can select the correct base class and the correct base element

```
   Pair<int, long>  p;

   p.set(0);  // set the int elem
   p.set(1L); // set the long elem
```

otherwise, via index, you can write

```
   p.set<0U>(3); // set the 1st (int) elem
   p.set<1U>(4); // set the 2nd (long) elem
```

Unfortunately, the `get()` doesn't receive an argument, so the type have to be explicited (via type or via index)

```
   p.get<int>();  // get the int elem value
   p.get<long>(); // get the long elem value

   p.get<0U>(); // get the 1st (int) elem value
   p.get<1U>(); // get the 2nd (long) elem value
```

Obviously, this didn't work when `T1` is equal to `T2`

The following is a (C++11) full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t I, typename, typename ... Ts>
struct getType
 { using type = typename getType<I-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct getType<0U, T, Ts...>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
class wrap
 {
   private:
      T  elem;

   public:
      void set (T const & t)
       { elem = t; }

      T get () const
       { return elem; }
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Pair : wrap<Ts>...
 {
   template <typename T>
   void set (T const & t)
    { wrap<T>::set(t); }

   template <std::size_t N, typename T>
   void set (T const & t)
    { wrap<typename getType<N, Ts...>::type>::set(t); }

   template <typename T>
   T get () const
    { return wrap<T>::get(); }

   template <std::size_t N>
   typename getType<N, Ts...>::type get ()
    { return wrap<typename getType<N, Ts...>::type>::get(); }
 };

int main()
 {
   //Pair<int, int>  p;  compilation error
   Pair<int, long, long long>  p;

   p.set(0);
   p.set(1L);
   p.set(2LL);

   std::cout << p.get<int>() << std::endl;       // print 0
   std::cout << p.get<long>() << std::endl;      // print 1
   std::cout << p.get<long long>() << std::endl; // print 2

   p.set<0U>(3);
   p.set<1U>(4);
   p.set<2U>(5);

   std::cout << p.get<0U>() << std::endl; // print 3
   std::cout << p.get<1U>() << std::endl; // print 4
   std::cout << p.get<2U>() << std::endl; // print 5
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is statically typed, so the argument given must be a template-argument instead a function-argument.

And while it will look like just one function each to the user, it's really two.

```
template <int i = 1> auto GetValue() -> std::enable_if_t<i == 1, T1> { return first; }
template <int i = 2> auto GetValue() -> std::enable_if_t<i == 2, T2> { return second; }
template <int i = 1> auto SetValue(T1 x) -> std::enable_if_t<i == 1> { first = x; }
template <int i = 2> auto SetValue(T2 x) -> std::enable_if_t<i == 2> { second = x; }
```

I use SFINAE on the return-type to remove the function from consideration unless the template-argument is right.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular situation, you should definitely prefer [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

You can simply overload `SetValue()` (provided `T1` and `T2` can be distinguished, if not you have a compile error):

```
void SetValue(T1 x)
{ first=x; }

void SetValue(T2 x)
{ second=x; }
```

Then, the compiler with find the best match for any call, i.e.

```
Pair<int,double> p;
p.SetValue(0);    // sets p.first
p.SetValue(0.0);  // sets p.second
```

With `GetValue()`, the information of which element you want to retrieve cannot be inferred from something like `p.GetValue()`, so you must provide it somehow. There are several options, such as

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,T1>,T>
GetValue() const
{ return first; }

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,T2>,T>
GetValue() const
{ return second; }
```

to be used like

```
auto a = p.GetValue<int>();
auto b = p.GetValue<double>();
```

but your initial version is good enough.